# ng-model in moved element not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text element which contains different ng directives like ng-model ng-change & that text element moved inside a div on run, after this none of this angular instances working.

`<input type="text" name="sample" ng-model="sampleCtrl.user.name" ng-change="changeName()">`

This input box moved inside div dynamically and that broke both directives. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: can u replicate this in a plunker

Comment: The issue is bcoz dynamically added HTML is not compiled by Angular. So if you need to add dynamically add HTML, than do this via Directive.